# Cannot use react devtools & redux devtools in build version of CRA

Tags: create-react-app, react-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

Using `create-react-app` with redux, and having both extension installed in chrome, I'm able to debug my app with these two.

However, after building my app `npm run build` the two extensions are not working.

Loading the redux devtools is with:

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
...
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers(...reducers),
  preloadedState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)),
);
```